# Image of square under Mobius Transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

Am i right that there is no Mobius transformation $$ h(z) $$ that sends a square to rectangle "A" with vertices in $$ 0, 2, i, i+2 $$because if we inscribe a cricle into square then it has 4 points $$ z_1,\ z_2,\ z_3,\ z_4 $$on a boundry on square therefore
$$ h(z_1), \ h(z_2), \ h(z_3), \ h(z_4)$$ also belongs to boundry of image of square under h and image of square is generlised circle whih is contradiction because we can't construct a cricle through theses points?

Comment: Right. Could perhaps be better explained - if you inscribe a circle in that square the image of the circle would be a circle inscribed in A, which is impossible.